# prerender doesn't work when meteor is not started as production

Tags: javascript, meteor, prerender

I use Prerender for the first time and it works almost well... in production only.
In fact, if I run my meteor server with `meteor --production` there is no error in the console and only a white page but if I run it with `meteor`, the phantom console print a lot of errors when I try to load a page with `?_escaped_fragment_=`.

[Here](https://pastebin.com/Ype4f0f4) are the packages I use

and [here](https://pastebin.com/iDUyxxmr) is what the phantom console print

Comment: That is strange. I don't recall having that particular issue myself, but I also didn't have a use case for pre-rendering non-production builds. Are you running with `meteor` or `meteor --production` on your public-facing server or is this just your local environment?

Comment: Try running our Chrome branch to render your pages in Chrome instead of PhantomJS. That should fix the issues you're seeing: https://github.com/prerender/prerender/tree/chrome